# How do i create permission on google sheet on docs in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-docs-api

How do i create permission on google sheet on docs. Here it's show the error

```
{
 "error": {
 "errors": [
  {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
     "message": "Insufficient Permission"
  }
 ],
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Insufficient Permission"
  }
}
```

here my code. i use php library.

```
function insertPermission($fileId) {

  $client = $this->getClient();
  $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
  $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

  $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(
        array(
            "role"=> "writer",
            "type"=> "domain",)  
    );

  try {
    return $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

After set permisson it's denied and return this error.

Comment: Welcome to stack.   In the future it would be best that you include the code you are using which has given this error message.   Seeing the code will assist users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The [permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) method can be used to insert permissions into a file on google drive.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions

{
  "role": "writer",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "test@test.com"
}
```

In order to run the above request the currently authenticated user must have been authenticated using the following scopes and of course have permissions on the file already

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

> insufficientPermissions

Means that the user you are authenticated with either hasn't granted your application permissions to make these changes or they themselves do not have the permissions.  First thing i would do would be check the scopes your application has requested and add the scopes needed and re-authenticated the user and try again.